# Converting array object into json in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using python shell npm package to invoke the python scripts from node.js.
My python Script returns json object which looks like this:

```
{"timestamp":"2005-10-30 10:45:33","error_code":"0","error_code_string":"Passed","mac_address":"00:0D:6F:41:AA:4A"}
```

When i run the below code i get the results in the form of array:

```
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell")
// import {PythonShell} from 'python-shell';

function Runpy(){

 const options = {
   mode: 'text',
   pythonPath: 'C:/Users/xyz/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python3',
   pythonOptions: ['-u'],
   scriptPath: 'D:/ABC',
   args : ['-test=3','-scan=200']
 };

 PythonShell.run('test_runner.py', options, function (err, results) {
   if (err) throw err;
   // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
   console.log('results: %j', results);
   //parsed = results.toString();
   //let parsedResult = JSON.parse(results);
   console.log(results);
 });
}

return Runpy();
```

Output:

```
results: ["{'timestamp': '2005-10-30 10:45:33', 'error_code': '0', 'error_code_string': 'Passed', 'mac_address': '00:0D:6F:41:AA:4A'}"]

[ '{\'timestamp\': \'2005-10-30 10:45:33\', \'error_code\': \'0\', \'error_code_string\': \'Passed\', \'mac_address\': \'00:0D:6F:41:AA:4A\'}' ]
```

When I try to parse the variable 'results' i get the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

I thought since results are already an object I am getting the error. So I tried to stringify the results and parse it. 
I am not getting any error then, but when I access individual items like timestamps by calling results. timestamp, I am getting as undefined.

Can anyone please suggest a way to convert this into JSON?

Comment: JSON requires double quotes. How did they get from your result above to the one below, turning `"` to `'`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte In the Python Script i am passing the JSON with double quotes, but i think python-shell npm package is replacing the double quotes with single quotes when trying to convert the result into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problemcomes from the single ticks `'`. They need to be double ticks `"` to be valid json. You can use `replace` to replace `'` with `"`.

```js
let results = ["{'timestamp': '2005-10-30 10:45:33', 'error_code': '0', 'error_code_string': 'Passed', 'mac_address': '00:0D:6F:41:AA:4A'}"];

results[0] = results[0].replace(/'/g, '"');

let parsed = JSON.parse(results[0])

console.log(parsed)
console.log(parsed.error_code)
```

Comment: The only real answer/solution is to fix the output on the server.

Comment: These types of search-and-destroy replaces should not be used in production code. Imagine `\`{"a": "mc'cool"}\``.

Comment: This solution fails if you have single quotes in `error_code_string`.